# Pandas Interpolate

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2    ║ NaN  ║
║ 4    ║ 5    ║
║ 12   ║ 11   ║
║ 23   ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ NaN  ║
║ NaN  ║ NaN  ║
║ NaN  ║ NaN  ║
║ NaN  ║ NaN  ║
║ 12   ║ NaN  ║
║ 7    ║ 6    ║
║ 3    ║ 8    ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

How can i get pandas to interpolate this to fill the values of col2 with the most recent values from col1?

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2    ║ 2    ║
║ 4    ║ 5    ║
║ 12   ║ 12   ║
║ 23   ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ NaN  ║ 23   ║
║ 12   ║ 12   ║
║ 7    ║ 6    ║
║ 3    ║ 3    ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

I'm new to pandas so if anyone has any suggestions that would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `ffill` and `fillna`

```
df.col2.fillna(df.col1.ffill())
```